# How to enable minification in universal-starter?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-universal, webpack-2

How to enable minification for [angular/universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)?

Right now the browser loads a 3.4MB **index.js** file:

[image]

Is `enableProdMode` responsible for minification?

If yes, universal-starter does have `enableProdMode` in **[server.ts](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/server.ts#L18)** and **[client.ts](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/client.ts#L9)** now.

If not, how to enable minification? Thanks

Comment: enableProdMode does exactly what the comment says, it speeds up rendering. Minification doesn't have anything to do with A2 or Universal app. The question applies to Webpack, it is done in Webpack config, you may check how [angular2-webpack-starter uses Uglify plugin](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js#L144-L164).

Comment: @estus thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from @mekya on GitHub.

```
npm run build:prod
```

which uses:

```
webpack --progress -p
```

inside of [package.json](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/package.json#L13) file.

And track [this](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/186) on GitHub for more info.